Translate JSON TO TABLES using JSON TABLE and Nested Path
select JT.*
FROM   JSON_TABLE ('{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }',
    '$'
    COLUMNS (
      product_key NUMBER PATH '$.general.product_key',
      group_subtype_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
      group_subtype_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
      variant_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.variant_id',
      variant_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.variant_name',
      rb_customer_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
      NESTED PATH '$.partnumbers[*]' COLUMNS (
        partnumber VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.partnumber',
        pn_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.pn_type',
        mat_status VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.mat_status',
      NESTED PATH '$.properties[*]' COLUMNS (
        property_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.property_id',
        property_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.property_name',
        value_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.value_id',
        value VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.value',
      NESTED PATH '$.document_numbers[*]' COLUMNS (
        document_number VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_number',
        document_verion NUMBER PATH '$.document_verion',
        document_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_type',
    NESTED PATH '$.target_markets[*]' COLUMNS (
        country_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.country_name',
        iso_code VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.iso_code',
    NESTED PATH '$.hierarchy_information[*]' COLUMNS (
          child_product NUMBER PATH '$'
        )))))))
      
  
  jt

Output:

Tried using Nested Path , but the Document numbers and Target MArkets cant be retrieved.
Kindly support,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Parse each of the nested JSON structures separately not using NESTED PATH in the initial JSON_TABLE and returning the arrays using FORMAT JSON and then you can use correlated sub-queries (using CROSS APPLY or CROSS JOIN LATERAL) to parse the individual queries and cross join the rows in each of the arrays.
The part numbers can be generated using a filter expression in the JSON path (rather than rows for each property and then pivoting). The target markets can be generated and aggregated so that a single row is always generated.
Like this:
SELECT jt.product_key,
       jt.group_subtype_id,
       jt.group_subtype_name,
       jt.variant_id,
       jt.variant_name,
       jt.rb_customer_id,
       pn.partnumber,
       pn.pn_type,
       pn.mat_status,
       pn.property_id_4_name || ':' || pn.property_id_4_value AS property_id_4,
       pn.property_id_5_name || ':' || pn.property_id_5_value AS property_id_5,
       pn.property_id_6_name || ':' || pn.property_id_6_value AS property_id_6,
       pn.property_id_7_name || ':' || pn.property_id_7_value AS property_id_7,
       pn.property_id_8_name || ':' || pn.property_id_8_value AS property_id_8,
       dn.document_number,
       dn.document_version,
       dn.document_type,
       tm.country_name,
       tm.iso_code,
       hi.child_product
FROM   (
         SELECT jt.*
         FROM   table_name t
                CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
                  t.value,
                  '$'
                  COLUMNS (
                    product_key           NUMBER        PATH '$.general.product_key',
                    group_subtype_id      NUMBER        PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
                    group_subtype_name    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
                    variant_id            NUMBER        PATH '$.general.variant_id',
                    variant_name          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.general.variant_name',
                    rb_customer_id        NUMBER        PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
                    partnumbers           CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.partnumbers',
                    document_numbers      CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.document_numbers',
                    target_markets        CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.target_markets',
                    hierarchy_information CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.hierarchy_information'
                  )
                ) jt
         WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
       ) jt
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.partnumbers,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           partnumber          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.partnumber',
           pn_type             VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.pn_type',
           mat_status          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.mat_status',
           property_id_4_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="4").property_name',
           property_id_4_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="4").value',
           property_id_5_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="5").property_name',
           property_id_5_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="5").value',
           property_id_6_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="6").property_name',
           property_id_6_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="6").value',
           property_id_7_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="7").property_name',
           property_id_7_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="7").value',
           property_id_8_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="8").property_name',
           property_id_8_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="8").value'
         )
       ) pn
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.document_numbers,
         '$[*]' COLUMNS (
             document_number  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_number',
             document_version VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_version',
             document_type    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_type'
           )
       ) dn
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(country_name, ':') AS country_name,
                LISTAGG(iso_code, ':') AS iso_code
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  jt.target_markets,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    country_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.country_name',
                    iso_code     VARCHAR2(3)   PATH '$.iso_code'
                  )
                )
       ) tm
       OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.hierarchy_information,
         '$[*]' COLUMNS (
             child_product    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$'
           )
       ) hi

Note: WHERE  ROWNUM > 0 looks like it does nothing as it will always be true but it is used to materialise the initial query which allows you to chain the correlated JSON_TABLEs.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }'
  FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PRODUCT_KEY
GROUP_SUBTYPE_ID
GROUP_SUBTYPE_NAME
VARIANT_ID
VARIANT_NAME
RB_CUSTOMER_ID
PARTNUMBER
PN_TYPE
MAT_STATUS
PROPERTY_ID_4
PROPERTY_ID_5
PROPERTY_ID_6
PROPERTY_ID_7
PROPERTY_ID_8
DOCUMENT_NUMBER
DOCUMENT_VERSION
DOCUMENT_TYPE
COUNTRY_NAME
ISO_CODE
CHILD_PRODUCT




501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234569871
05
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
0123456789
01
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234569870
05
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234567890
01
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null



fiddle

Your nested path expressions are nested - that means you're looking for the document_numbers attribute within the properties node. With some formatting that becomes clear. To get the attributes of document_numbers and target_markets, make this small change:
select JT.*
FROM   
JSON_TABLE ('{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }',
    '$'
    COLUMNS (
        product_key NUMBER PATH '$.general.product_key',
        group_subtype_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
        group_subtype_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
        variant_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.variant_id',
        variant_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.general.variant_name',
        rb_customer_id NUMBER PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
        NESTED PATH '$.partnumbers[*]' COLUMNS (
            partnumber VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.partnumber',
            pn_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.pn_type',
            mat_status VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.mat_status',
            NESTED PATH '$.properties[*]' COLUMNS (
                property_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.property_id',
                property_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.property_name',
                value_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.value_id',
                value VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.value'
            )
        ),
        NESTED PATH '$.document_numbers[*]' COLUMNS (
            document_number VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_number',
            document_verion NUMBER PATH '$.document_verion',
            document_type VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.document_type'
        ),
        NESTED PATH '$.target_markets[*]' COLUMNS (
            country_name VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.country_name',
            iso_code VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.iso_code'
        )                  
    )
) jt

Note that this will give you more rows, since there is no relationship between the elements of the individual objects.

Hello @KOEN LOSTRIE, thanks for your reply. Product key is the Primary key for this record. Is there any way to use the  product key in the nested path and apply join condition to get distinct records

There most likely is. Asking a followup question in the comments is not a good practice. This question is about getting the data for the document_numbers and target_markets. I answered that question. Now it is up to you. I suggest posting another one for this new question. Be as detailed as possible, I'd suggest showing what output you are expecting. You say "distinct records" so show what exactly you mean by that.
