Converting JSON response into Tables in ORacle database
{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }

Need this output :

I tried using nested path , but not getting expected output

do you need a sql query to convert json and insert in orcale db?

Make it easy to assist you, simplify! Also note that most people here want data as properly formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

This probably should be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78553158/1509264 as it appears to be exactly the same question (with less detail).

This is a bit complicated cause your json sample data. For 1 "general" row there is 1 "partnumbers" row having 5 "properties" rows which are transposed to columns. For the same 1 "general" row there are 4 rows for "document_numbers" and 3 rows for "target_markets" (transformed to list). Since you want 4 rows of data in your expected result you should further process (Main SQL) the data fetched (grid cte) from your JSON response.
Comments in code too...
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :     (json)
    jst AS
        ( Select 
'{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }'  as JSTXT  From Dual),

Use JSON_TABLE() to fetch rows and columns from your JSON response string:
... create a cte (named it grid)
    grid AS
        ( Select  x.PRODUCT_KEY, x.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID, 
                  x.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME "GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME", x.VARIANT_ID "VARIANT_ID", x.VARIANT_NAME "VARIANT_NAME", x.RB_CUSTOMER "RB_CUSTOMER",
                  x.PARTNUMBER "PARTNUMBER", x.PN_TYPE "PN_TYPE", x.MAT_STATUS "MAT_STATUS", 
                  --  use Case expressions to get properties as columns instead of rows
                  Case When x.PROPERTY_ID = 4 Then x.PROPERTY_NAME || ': ' || x.VALUE End "PROPERTY_4", 
                  Case When x.PROPERTY_ID = 5 Then x.PROPERTY_NAME || ': ' || x.VALUE End "PROPERTY_5", 
                  Case When x.PROPERTY_ID = 6 Then x.PROPERTY_NAME || ': ' || x.VALUE End "PROPERTY_6", 
                  Case When x.PROPERTY_ID = 7 Then x.PROPERTY_NAME || ': ' || x.VALUE End "PROPERTY_7", 
                  Case When x.PROPERTY_ID = 8 Then x.PROPERTY_NAME || ': ' || x.VALUE End "PROPERTY_8", 
                  --
                  x.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, x.DOCUMENT_VERSION, x.DOCUMENT_TYPE,
                  -- use LISTAGG() to get lists (Country names and ISO codes)
                  LISTAGG(Distinct x.COUNTRY_NAME, ':') WITHIN GROUP (Order By x.COUNTRY_NAME) Over(Partition By x.PRODUCT_KEY, x.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID, x.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, x.DOCUMENT_VERSION, x.DOCUMENT_TYPE) "COUNTRY_NAME", 
                  LISTAGG(Distinct x.ISO_CODE, ':') WITHIN GROUP (Order By x.ISO_CODE) Over(Partition By x.PRODUCT_KEY, x.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID, x.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, x.DOCUMENT_VERSION, x.DOCUMENT_TYPE) "ISO_CODE"
          From    jst j, 
                  JSON_TABLE( j.JSTXT, '$'
                   COLUMNS ( PRODUCT_KEY           VARCHAR2(12)     PATH '$.general.product_key',
                             GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID     NUMBER           PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
                             GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME   VARCHAR2(24)     PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
                             VARIANT_ID            NUMBER           PATH '$.general.variant_id',
                             VARIANT_NAME          VARCHAR2(16)     PATH '$.general.variant_name',
                             RB_CUSTOMER           NUMBER           PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
                               NESTED '$.partnumbers[*]'
                                  COLUMNS ( PARTNUMBER      VARCHAR2(12)   PATH '$.partnumber',
                                            PN_TYPE         VARCHAR2(12)   PATH '$.pn_type',
                                            MAT_STATUS      VARCHAR2(12)   PATH '$.mat_status',
                                                NESTED '$.properties[*]'
                                                    COLUMNS ( PROPERTY_ID     VARCHAR2(16)   PATH '$.property_id',
                                                              PROPERTY_NAME   VARCHAR2(32)   PATH '$.property_name',
                                                              VALUE_ID        NUMBER(8)      PATH '$.value_id',
                                                              VALUE           VARCHAR2(24)   PATH '$.value'
                                                            )
                                          ),
                              NESTED '$.document_numbers[*]'
                                  COLUMNS ( DOCUMENT_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(12)    PATH '$.document_number', 
                                            DOCUMENT_VERSION VARCHAR2(12)    PATH '$.document_version',
                                            DOCUMENT_TYPE    VARCHAR2(12)    PATH '$.document_type'
                                          ), 
                              NESTED '$.target_markets[*]'
                                  COLUMNS ( COUNTRY_NAME  VARCHAR2(30)    PATH '$.country_name',
                                            ISO_CODE      VARCHAR2(2)     PATH '$.iso_code'
                                          )
                          )
                      ) x
      )

... Process resultset to get ridd of duplicates and to format your expected result :
--      M a i n    S Q L :
--  self joined grid cte to format your expected result
SELECT  g.PRODUCT_KEY, g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME, g.VARIANT_ID, g.VARIANT_NAME,  g.RB_CUSTOMER, 
        Max(g.PARTNUMBER) "PARTNUMBER", Max(g.PN_TYPE) "PN_TYPE", 
        Max(g.PROPERTY_4) "PROPERTY_4", Max(g.PROPERTY_5) "PROPERTY_5", Max(g.PROPERTY_6) "PROPERTY_6", Max(g.PROPERTY_7) "PROPERTY_7", Max(g.PROPERTY_8) "PROPERTY_8",
        doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, doc.DOCUMENT_VERSION, doc.DOCUMENT_TYPE,
        Max(g.COUNTRY_NAME) "COUNTRY_NAME", Max(g.ISO_CODE) "ISO_CODE"
FROM        grid g
INNER JOIN  grid doc ON(doc.PRODUCT_KEY = doc.PRODUCT_KEY And doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER Is Not Null And g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID = doc.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID)
WHERE       g.DOCUMENT_NUMBER Is Null
GROUP BY    g.PRODUCT_KEY, g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME, g.VARIANT_ID, g.VARIANT_NAME, g.RB_CUSTOMER,
            doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, doc.DOCUMENT_VERSION, doc.DOCUMENT_TYPE

/*      R e s u l t :
PRODUCT_KEY  GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME      VARIANT_ID VARIANT_NAME     RB_CUSTOMER PARTNUMBER   PN_TYPE      PROPERTY_4                                                 PROPERTY_5                                                 PROPERTY_6                                                 PROPERTY_7                                                 PROPERTY_8                                                 DOCUMENT_NUM DOCUMENT_VER DOCUMENT_TYP COUNTRY_NAME                               ISO_CODE    
------------ ------------------------ ---------- ---------------- ----------- ------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------------------------------------ ------------
501088       Wheel Speed Sensor                6 DF22                  287383 F04FD009BD   Series OEM   ASIC P/N: 8905502648                                       ASIC type: TLE4942                                         Axle: Front / Rear Right                                   Base Type - Development P/N: FFF                           Base Type - Released P/N: SSS                              0123456789   01           TCD          Albania:Belize:Central African Republic    AL:BZ:CF    
501088       Wheel Speed Sensor                6 DF22                  287383 F04FD009BD   Series OEM   ASIC P/N: 8905502648                                       ASIC type: TLE4942                                         Axle: Front / Rear Right                                   Base Type - Development P/N: FFF                           Base Type - Released P/N: SSS                              1234567890   01           TCD          Albania:Belize:Central African Republic    AL:BZ:CF    
501088       Wheel Speed Sensor                6 DF22                  287383 F04FD009BD   Series OEM   ASIC P/N: 8905502648                                       ASIC type: TLE4942                                         Axle: Front / Rear Right                                   Base Type - Development P/N: FFF                           Base Type - Released P/N: SSS                              1234569870   05           TCD          Albania:Belize:Central African Republic    AL:BZ:CF    
501088       Wheel Speed Sensor                6 DF22                  287383 F04FD009BD   Series OEM   ASIC P/N: 8905502648                                       ASIC type: TLE4942                                         Axle: Front / Rear Right                                   Base Type - Development P/N: FFF                           Base Type - Released P/N: SSS                              1234569871   05           TCD          Albania:Belize:Central African Republic    AL:BZ:CF    */

If there could be multiple "partnumbers" rows then do not aggregate (Max) PARTNUMBER and PN_TYPE columns - move them to Group By clause and filter in where clause for PARTNUMBER Is NoT Null:
--      M a i n    S Q L :
--  in case of multiple partnumbers - changed aggregations and groupings for PARTNUMBER, PN_TYPE and filter with where clause for PARTNUMBER Is Not Null
SELECT  g.PRODUCT_KEY, g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME, g.VARIANT_ID, g.VARIANT_NAME,  g.RB_CUSTOMER, 
        g.PARTNUMBER "PARTNUMBER", g.PN_TYPE "PN_TYPE", 
        Max(g.PROPERTY_4) "PROPERTY_4", Max(g.PROPERTY_5) "PROPERTY_5", Max(g.PROPERTY_6) "PROPERTY_6", Max(g.PROPERTY_7) "PROPERTY_7", Max(g.PROPERTY_8) "PROPERTY_8",
        doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, doc.DOCUMENT_VERSION, doc.DOCUMENT_TYPE,
        Max(g.COUNTRY_NAME) "COUNTRY_NAME", Max(g.ISO_CODE) "ISO_CODE"
FROM        grid g
INNER JOIN  grid doc ON(doc.PRODUCT_KEY = doc.PRODUCT_KEY And doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER Is Not Null And g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID = doc.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_ID)
WHERE       g.DOCUMENT_NUMBER Is Null And g.PARTNUMBER Is Not Null
GROUP BY    g.PRODUCT_KEY, g.GROUP_SUB_TYPE_NAME, g.VARIANT_ID, 
            g.VARIANT_NAME, g.RB_CUSTOMER,
            g.PARTNUMBER, g.PN_TYPE,    --  added here - not aggregated       
            doc.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, doc.DOCUMENT_VERSION, doc.DOCUMENT_TYPE


If there are two items in the part_numbers array then this will only display one of them fiddle

@MT0 If there are it should be in sample data (and it isn't), but if there are then the aggregation and grouping should be adjusted (added to the answer). NESTED PATH could be an option to solve this and, arguably, it's more readable than using cross apply and cross lateral, rownum, clobs etc. though that certainly is an option to get the result too...

Parse each of the nested JSON structures separately not using NESTED PATH in the initial JSON_TABLE and returning the arrays using FORMAT JSON and then you can use correlated sub-queries (using CROSS APPLY or CROSS JOIN LATERAL) to parse the individual queries and cross join the rows in each of the arrays.
The part numbers can be generated using a filter expression in the JSON path (rather than rows for each property and then pivoting). The target markets can be generated and aggregated so that a single row is always generated.
Like this:
SELECT jt.product_key,
       jt.group_subtype_id,
       jt.group_subtype_name,
       jt.variant_id,
       jt.variant_name,
       jt.rb_customer_id,
       pn.partnumber,
       pn.pn_type,
       pn.mat_status,
       pn.property_id_4_name || ':' || pn.property_id_4_value AS property_id_4,
       pn.property_id_5_name || ':' || pn.property_id_5_value AS property_id_5,
       pn.property_id_6_name || ':' || pn.property_id_6_value AS property_id_6,
       pn.property_id_7_name || ':' || pn.property_id_7_value AS property_id_7,
       pn.property_id_8_name || ':' || pn.property_id_8_value AS property_id_8,
       dn.document_number,
       dn.document_version,
       dn.document_type,
       tm.country_name,
       tm.iso_code,
       hi.child_product
FROM   (
         SELECT jt.*
         FROM   table_name t
                CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
                  t.value,
                  '$'
                  COLUMNS (
                    product_key           NUMBER        PATH '$.general.product_key',
                    group_subtype_id      NUMBER        PATH '$.general.group_subtype_id',
                    group_subtype_name    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.general.group_subtype_name',
                    variant_id            NUMBER        PATH '$.general.variant_id',
                    variant_name          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.general.variant_name',
                    rb_customer_id        NUMBER        PATH '$.general.rb_customer_id',
                    partnumbers           CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.partnumbers',
                    document_numbers      CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.document_numbers',
                    target_markets        CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.target_markets',
                    hierarchy_information CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.hierarchy_information'
                  )
                ) jt
         WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
       ) jt
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.partnumbers,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           partnumber          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.partnumber',
           pn_type             VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.pn_type',
           mat_status          VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.mat_status',
           property_id_4_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="4").property_name',
           property_id_4_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="4").value',
           property_id_5_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="5").property_name',
           property_id_5_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="5").value',
           property_id_6_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="6").property_name',
           property_id_6_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="6").value',
           property_id_7_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="7").property_name',
           property_id_7_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="7").value',
           property_id_8_name  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="8").property_name',
           property_id_8_value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.properties[*]?(@.property_id=="8").value'
         )
       ) pn
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.document_numbers,
         '$[*]' COLUMNS (
             document_number  VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_number',
             document_version VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_version',
             document_type    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.document_type'
           )
       ) dn
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(country_name, ':') AS country_name,
                LISTAGG(iso_code, ':') AS iso_code
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  jt.target_markets,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    country_name VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.country_name',
                    iso_code     VARCHAR2(3)   PATH '$.iso_code'
                  )
                )
       ) tm
       OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         jt.hierarchy_information,
         '$[*]' COLUMNS (
             child_product    VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$'
           )
       ) hi

Note: WHERE  ROWNUM > 0 looks like it does nothing as it will always be true but it is used to materialise the initial query which allows you to chain the correlated JSON_TABLEs.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '{
    "general": {
      "product_key": "501088",
      "group_subtype_id": 1,
      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
      "variant_id": 6,
      "variant_name": "DF22",
      "rb_customer_id": 287383
    },
    "partnumbers": [
      {
        "partnumber": "F04FD009BD",
        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
        "mat_status": "00 - planned",
        "properties": [
          {"property_id":4,"property_name":"ASIC P/N","value_id":38,"value":"8905502648"},
          {"property_id":5,"property_name":"ASIC type","value_id":56,"value":"TLE4942"},
          {"property_id":6,"property_name":"Axle","value_id":62,"value":"Front / Rear Right"},
          {"property_id":7,"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N","value_id":72,"value":"FFF"},
          {"property_id":8,"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N","value_id":73,"value":"SSS"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "document_numbers": [
      {"document_number":"1234569871","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"0123456789","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234569870","document_version":"05","document_type":"TCD"},
      {"document_number":"1234567890","document_version":"01","document_type":"TCD"}
    ],
    "target_markets": [
      {"country_name":"Belize","iso_code":"BZ"},
      {"country_name":"Central African Republic","iso_code":"CF"},
      {"country_name":"Albania","iso_code":"AL"}
    ]
  }'
  FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PRODUCT_KEY
GROUP_SUBTYPE_ID
GROUP_SUBTYPE_NAME
VARIANT_ID
VARIANT_NAME
RB_CUSTOMER_ID
PARTNUMBER
PN_TYPE
MAT_STATUS
PROPERTY_ID_4
PROPERTY_ID_5
PROPERTY_ID_6
PROPERTY_ID_7
PROPERTY_ID_8
DOCUMENT_NUMBER
DOCUMENT_VERSION
DOCUMENT_TYPE
COUNTRY_NAME
ISO_CODE
CHILD_PRODUCT




501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234569871
05
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
0123456789
01
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234569870
05
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null


501088
1
Wheel Speed Sensor
6
DF22
287383
F04FD009BD
Series OEM
00 - planned
ASIC P/N:8905502648
ASIC type:TLE4942
Axle:Front / Rear Right
Base Type - Development P/N:FFF
Base Type - Released P/N:SSS
1234567890
01
TCD
Belize:Central African Republic:Albania
BZ:CF:AL
null



fiddle
